# Hulls merging in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, merge, convex-hull

Suppose you have two hulls H1 and H2 and you want to merge them into H. (See the picture).
[image]

Is there an algorithm on that?
Maybe opencv has one already built-in?
Could anyone provide a code snippet?

Thanks!!!

Comment: run `convexHull` on the union of the points of the two hulls?

Comment: Like that ? list(set().union(hull1, hull2))

Comment: you don't even need an actual union call, just concatenate the lists of points and calculate a new convex hull from the result.

Comment: I dont know something is not working for me, could you post a code snippet by making two dummy hulls ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm for merging two convex hulls in O(n1+n2) time.You just need to find upper and lower tangent for the given hulls and then exclude the points inside the upper and lower tangents.

Check out [Tangents between two Convex Polygons](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tangents-two-convex-polygons/)
, it has code snippet too.